# Greedy/non-greedy quantifiers in ABAP regular expressions

Tags: regex, abap

I would like to extract 2 things from this string: `| 2013.10.10 FEL felsz`

1. regex -> Date field -> the needed value will be only the `2013.10.10` (in this case)
2. regex -> String between `2013.10.10` and `felsz` string -> the needed value will be only the `FEL` string (in this case).

I tried with the following regexes as with not too much success:

1. `(.*?<p/\s>.*?)(?=\s)`
2. `(.*?<p/("[0-9]+">.*?)(?=\s)`

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For anyone wondering about **ABAP**. Just looked it up: `ABAP` (`Advanced Business Application Programming`) originally called Allgemeiner Berichts-Aufbereitungs-Prozessor (fantastic name and German for "general report creation processor"). Regex info: https://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABENREGULAR_EXPRESSIONS.htm

Comment: Just an addition to all of the answers provided - you do know the report `DEMO_REGEX_TOY`?

Comment: Yes, I utilized this riport earlier and then I discovered that for instance, the "?" keyword is not supported. I don't understand it really but it's okay. It's a very useful riport during the test phase of any regex in ABAP environment.

Comment: Regular syntax Simplified syntax 
* * 
+ not supported 
{ } \{ \} 
( ) \( \) 
[ ] [ ] 
| not supported 
(?= ) (?! ) not supported 
(?: ) not supported

Comment: @Freddiboy your last remark about supported operators is wrong. Are supported (at least): [chaining operators, alternatives, subgroups, subgroups with registration](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenregex_syntax_operators.htm), [preview conditions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenregex_search.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENREGEX_SEARCH_6), etc. ABAP uses the [Boost.Regex Library](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenregular_expressions.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, since ABAP doesn't allow non-greedy match with `*?`, if you can count on `felsz` occurring only immediately after the second portion you want to match you could use:

```
(\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d) (.*) felsz
```

(PS: **Invalidated first answer:** in non-ABAP systems where `*?` is supported, the following regex will get both values into submatches. The date will be in submatch 1 and the other value (FEL in this case) will be in submatch 2 : `(\d{4}.\d\d.\d\d) (.*?) felsz)

Comment: I use it in ABAP environment, it seems that the "?" char is forbidden. Is there any other method use regex without use the "?"?

Comment: The ? makes the .* be non-greedy. Thus with the ? it will stop when it sees felsz. If felsz will only occur once within the input text and greedy matching isn't a problem you could just remove the ? from the regex leaving you with `(\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d) (.*) felsz`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I utilize the key word: "SUBMATCHES" and the problem solved.

Comment: Abap won't allow you to use question mark to trigger lazy matching, which means this answer won't work.

Comment: So non-greedy behavior in ABAP is not supported yet?

Comment: just came here with the same problem - no it is not supported (at least in my current version :) )

I now left out the lazy-modifier `?` and disallowed the closing character (had only one, but should be doable with a certain word via negative lookahead) by changing `.*` to `[^>]*` ,  if `>` is your closing character

Answer (score 1):

Is "felsz" variable? Can the white space vary? Can your date format vary? If not:

```
\| (\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}) (.*?) felsz
```

Otherwise:

```
\|\s+?(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s+?(.*?)\s+?[a-z]+
```

Then access capture groups 1/2.

Comment: No, "felsz" is a constant, but I use it in ABAP environment and it seems that the "?" char is forbidden. Is there any other method use regex without use the "?"?

Comment: Without the .*? would be: `\|\s+(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s+([^\s]+)\s+[a-z]+`

Comment: "?" is a widely-used RegEx metacharacter. Perhaps you need to escape it when creating your RegExp object?

Comment: Unfortunately in ABAP environment, it seems that the "?" char is not supported yet. Perhaps with the latest patch will solve this problem. Anyway with the keyword "SUBMATCES" solved the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Freddiboy, it's worth a shot and it may or may not work, but what about trying `{0,1}` in place of `?`? It has the exact same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The regex

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

matches `2013.10.10` in the given string. Explanation and demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/bL7eO0

```
(?<=\d ).*(?= felsz)
```

should work to match `FEL`. Explanation and demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/pV2mW5

If you want them in capturing groups, you could use the regex:

```
\| (\d+\.\d+\.\d+) (.+?) .*
```

Explanation and demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/rQ6uU4

Comment: To the 2nd "FEL" regex: I use it in ABAP environment, it seems that the "?" char is forbidden. Is there any other method use regex without use the "?"?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`(?:\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s)(.*)\s` [See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/nR5lM2).

This matches `FEL`

Some things I took for granted:

1. the date always comes first and is a mix of numbers and periods
2. the date is always followed by a space
3. the word to capture is always followed by a space
4. the word to capture never contains a space

Comment: In ABAP environment it seems that it doesn't work properly. It gives back the whole string. Anyway your hypothesis is well.

Comment: I have zero experience with ABAP, just added the tag to your question. I tried adding a non-capture group, not sure if it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I utilize the key word in ABAP: "SUBMATCHES" and the problem solved.

Comment: Great, glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `FEL` is always a single word (that is, delimited by a space), you could use the following expression:

```
(\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d) ([^\s]+) (.*)
```